# Why does 'ipsec statusall' not show any connections?

Tags: vpn, ubuntu-14.04, ipsec, strongswan

I've finally been able to get a tunnel between my computer (strongswan) and a Zyxel Zywall 110 up and running.

I'm connecting using certificates, and judging from the logs the actual VPN connection seems to get established.

```
May  4 14:14:49 user charon-nm: 10[IKE] authentication of 'remote.company.com' with RSA signature successful
May  4 14:14:49 user charon-nm: 10[IKE] IKE_SA Company[1] established between 192.168.43.101[C=NO, CN=user]...X.X.X.X[remote.company.com]
May  4 14:14:49 user charon-nm: 10[IKE] scheduling rekeying in 35793s
May  4 14:14:49 user charon-nm: 10[IKE] maximum IKE_SA lifetime 36393s
May  4 14:14:49 user charon-nm: 10[CFG] handling INTERNAL_IP4_NETMASK attribute failed
May  4 14:14:49 user charon-nm: 10[IKE] installing new virtual IP 192.168.100.6
May  4 14:14:49 user charon: 14[KNL] 192.168.100.6 appeared on wlan0
May  4 14:14:49 user avahi-daemon[645]: Registering new address record for 192.168.100.6 on wlan0.IPv4.
May  4 14:14:49 user charon-nm: 10[IKE] received ESP_TFC_PADDING_NOT_SUPPORTED, not using ESPv3 TFC padding
May  4 14:14:49 user charon-nm: 10[IKE] CHILD_SA Company{1} established with SPIs c71e085c_i 46449091_o and TS 192.168.100.6/32 === X.X.X.X/32 
May  4 14:14:49 user NetworkManager[1076]: <info> VPN connection 'Company' (IP4 Config Get) reply received from old-style plugin.
May  4 14:14:49 user NetworkManager[1076]: nm_ip4_config_add_nameserver: assertion 'nameserver > 0' failed
May  4 14:14:49 user NetworkManager[1076]: nm_ip4_config_add_wins: assertion 'wins > 0' failed
May  4 14:14:49 user NetworkManager[1076]: nm_ip4_config_add_wins: assertion 'wins > 0' failed
May  4 14:14:49 user NetworkManager[1076]: <info> Tunnel Device: tun0
May  4 14:14:49 user NetworkManager[1076]: <info> IPv4 configuration:
May  4 14:14:49 user NetworkManager[1076]: <info>   Internal Address: 192.168.100.6
May  4 14:14:49 user NetworkManager[1076]: <info>   Internal Prefix: 32
May  4 14:14:49 user NetworkManager[1076]: <info>   Internal Point-to-Point Address: 0.0.0.0
May  4 14:14:49 user NetworkManager[1076]: <info>   Maximum Segment Size (MSS): 0
May  4 14:14:49 user NetworkManager[1076]: <info>   Forbid Default Route: yes
May  4 14:14:49 user NetworkManager[1076]: <info>   Internal DNS: 192.168.16.2
May  4 14:14:49 user NetworkManager[1076]: <info>   DNS Domain: '(none)'
May  4 14:14:49 user NetworkManager[1076]: <info> No IPv6 configuration
May  4 14:14:49 user charon-nm: 14[KNL] interface tun0 activated
May  4 14:14:49 user charon: 07[KNL] interface tun0 activated
May  4 14:14:49 user kernel: [15417.710286] brcmsmac bcma0:1: brcms_ops_bss_info_changed: arp filtering: 2 addresses (implement)
May  4 14:14:49 user charon-nm: 05[KNL] 192.168.100.6 appeared on tun0
May  4 14:14:49 user charon: 11[KNL] 192.168.100.6 appeared on tun0
May  4 14:14:50 user NetworkManager[1076]: <info> VPN connection 'Company' (IP Config Get) complete.
```

However, even though the VPN seems to be established it seems that the output of `ipsec statusall` does not agree.

```
Status of IKE charon daemon (strongSwan 5.1.2, Linux 3.19.0-33-generic, x86_64):
  uptime: 4 hours, since May 04 09:57:53 2016
  malloc: sbrk 2568192, mmap 0, used 330496, free 2237696
  worker threads: 11 of 16 idle, 5/0/0/0 working, job queue: 0/0/0/0, scheduled: 0
  loaded plugins: charon test-vectors aes rc2 sha1 sha2 md4 md5 rdrand random nonce x509 revocation constraints pkcs1 pkcs7 pkcs8 pkcs12 pem openssl xcbc cmac hmac ctr ccm gcm attr kernel-netlink resolve socket-default stroke updown eap-identity addrblock
Listening IP addresses:
  192.168.43.101
  192.168.100.6
  10.0.3.1
  192.168.100.6
Connections:
Security Associations (0 up, 0 connecting):
  none
```

Last, the output of `ip route show` gives me the following.

```
default via 192.168.43.1 dev wlan0  proto static 
10.0.3.0/24 dev lxcbr0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.0.3.1 
192.168.43.0/24 dev wlan0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.43.101  metric 9
```

The VPN connection has been configured with Network Manager, and I'm using certificates to establish the connection. I am unable to reach any resources on the network which I've established the VPN connection to.

Am I missing something in the configuration? What could I be missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The IKE daemon used by the [NetworkManager plugin](https://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/NetworkManager) (`charon-nm`) is different than the regular IKE daemon (`charon`) that you interact with via the `ipsec` script.

Therefore, you won't be able to see the status of connections established via NetworkManager plugin in `ipsec statusall` as that will only show you connections and SAs managed by the regular daemon, which are configured in `ipsec.conf`.